# jquery, dont execute script code on html()

Tags: jquery

I've this code

```
jQuery('#div').html('<script>alert("aaa")</script>')
```

I remember that in the past this was a problem because script was not executed, but now it's executed, how I can make it don't execute?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: so alert is triggered because of what event?

Comment: Do you want to filter out the `script` tags before appending html code to the DOM or do you want to prevent the execution of it but append the script tags to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you would need to use this for but you could put it in a function, then call that function when you want to execute.

Comment: Just trying to present an idea since it isn't very clear what the user was trying to accomplish. Didn't realize that wasn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the DOM element innerHTML.

```
jQuery('#maincontent').get(0).innerHTML = ('<script>alert("aaa")</script> ')
```

This way the script is not being evaled, not sure how to disable that behavior on jquery thoguht

Answer (score 0):

you can add a fake type and then remove it

```
$('#div').html('<script type="text/none">alert("aaa")</script>')
$('#div').removeAttr('type')
```